# I want to find Word similarity Using WordNet

Tags: java, netbeans, wordnet, ws4j

I am doing final year project on "web video categorization", in which one part is to find the similar (synonyms) words for a particular word and I want to remove similar terms from it.

I know Java language, so I chosen "Word Similarity For Java" **ws4j**

For that I have only used [WS4J1.0.1](http://code.google.com/p/ws4j/downloads/) jar file , even I have not downloaded any extra files like **WordNet** lexical database or **sqlite** database to store it. Because in that website they have mentioned that all are contained as precompiled in this jar file.

When I executed Demo program [SimilarityCalculationDemo.java](https://code.google.com/p/ws4j/source/browse/trunk/edu.cmu.lti.ws4j/src/main/java/edu/cmu/lti/ws4j/demo/SimilarityCalculationDemo.java), I got the following errors:

```
    java.sql.BatchUpdateException: batch entry 0: [SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image is malformed (database disk image is malformed)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeBatch(Stmt.java:226)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeBatch(Stmt.java:226)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.createIndexIfNotExists(SQL.java:118)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.createSQLConnection(SQL.java:98)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.<init>(SQL.java:55)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.<clinit>(SQL.java:45)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.WordDAO.findWordsByLemmaAndPos(WordDAO.java:124)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.util.WordNetUtil.wordToSynsets(WordNetUtil.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.lti.lexical_db.NictWordNet.getAllConcepts(NictWordNet.java:38)
                             atedu.cmu.lti.ws4j.util.WordSimilarityCalculator.calcRelatednessOfWords(WordSimilarityCalculator.java:79)
    at edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.RelatednessCalculator.calcRelatednessOfWords(RelatednessCalculator.java:61)
    at web_cat.SimilarityCalculationDemo.run(SimilarityCalculationDemo.java:37)
    at web_cat.SimilarityCalculationDemo.main(SimilarityCalculationDemo.java:43)
        java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image is malformed (database disk image is malformed)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:113)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.setPragmaCacheSize(SQL.java:137)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.createSQLConnection(SQL.java:99)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.<init>(SQL.java:55)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.<clinit>(SQL.java:45)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.WordDAO.findWordsByLemmaAndPos(WordDAO.java:124)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.util.WordNetUtil.wordToSynsets(WordNetUtil.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.lti.lexical_db.NictWordNet.getAllConcepts(NictWordNet.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.util.WordSimilarityCalculator.calcRelatednessOfWords(WordSimilarityCalculator.java:79)
    at edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.RelatednessCalculator.calcRelatednessOfWords(RelatednessCalculator.java:61)
    at web_cat.SimilarityCalculationDemo.run(SimilarityCalculationDemo.java:37)
    at web_cat.SimilarityCalculationDemo.main(SimilarityCalculationDemo.java:43)
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image is malformed (database disk image is malformed)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:42)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:404)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:399)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:383)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.prepareStatements(SQL.java:151)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.<init>(SQL.java:56)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.SQL.<clinit>(SQL.java:45)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.WordDAO.findWordsByLemmaAndPos(WordDAO.java:124)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.util.WordNetUtil.wordToSynsets(WordNetUtil.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.lti.lexical_db.NictWordNet.getAllConcepts(NictWordNet.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.util.WordSimilarityCalculator.calcRelatednessOfWords(WordSimilarityCalculator.java:79)
    at edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.RelatednessCalculator.calcRelatednessOfWords(RelatednessCalculator.java:61)
    at web_cat.SimilarityCalculationDemo.run(SimilarityCalculationDemo.java:37)
    at web_cat.SimilarityCalculationDemo.main(SimilarityCalculationDemo.java:43)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.db.WordDAO.findWordsByLemmaAndPos(WordDAO.java:125)
    at edu.cmu.lti.jawjaw.util.WordNetUtil.wordToSynsets(WordNetUtil.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.lti.lexical_db.NictWordNet.getAllConcepts(NictWordNet.java:38)
    at edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.util.WordSimilarityCalculator.calcRelatednessOfWords(WordSimilarityCalculator.java:79)
    at edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.RelatednessCalculator.calcRelatednessOfWords(RelatednessCalculator.java:61)
    at web_cat.SimilarityCalculationDemo.run(SimilarityCalculationDemo.java:37)
    at web_cat.SimilarityCalculationDemo.main(SimilarityCalculationDemo.java:43)
Java Result: 1
```

I am Using Netbeans IDE 7.4 with JDK 6.

Could any please assist me, how to overcome from this problem, because there is a less documentation available in the internet about **ws4j**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I could not reproduce your error. For me it just worked perfectly out of the box, using eclipse, so I'll try to help you reproducing exactly what I've did

1. download ws4j-1.0.1.jar from https://ws4j.googlecode.com/files/ws4j-1.0.1.jar and ensure it's size after the download is 41,362,723  bytes (at least, that's what eclipse told me in my linux box)
2. Use java 7
3. Create a simple eclipse project and drop the jar there. Then add the jar to the build path 
   (right click -> build path -> add)
4. Create an appropriate package and class to accommodate the demo class
5. Just run the demo and you'll get something like

   ```
   edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.HirstStOnge   0.0
   edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.LeacockChodorow   1.3862943611198906
   edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Lesk  0.0
   edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.WuPalmer  0.4
   edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Resnik    2.5031573470157453
   edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.JiangConrath  0.11150424023847051
   edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Lin   0.3582442863008455
   edu.cmu.lti.ws4j.impl.Path  0.14285714285714285
   Done in 1951 msec.
   ```

[image]

Comment: I am using Windows8 Operating System with NetBeans IDE 7.4 . Is there any problem in the usage of Operating System? because I did same thing as you did in running the demo file

Comment: in theory, no. I've run mine in linux

Comment: are you sure your jar is not corrupted?

Comment: I have just downloaded the jar file from the same link on yesterday and run it on NetBeansIDE 7.4. but it shows same Runtime error

Comment: you just saved my day, Although all i needed was to download the original ws4j.jar file